# MySQL 5.6.10 installation error

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error while installing MySQL 5.6.10. I have other versions of MySQL (5.1 and 4.1) installed and there seems to be a conflict in the my.cnf.

Removing `/etc/my.cnf` is not an option.

```
[amitra@dev4.lab user.amitra]$ sudo /usr/local/mysql5610/scripts/mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local/mysql5610/ --datadir=/var/home/amitra/mysql5610/user.amitra

Installing MySQL system tables...2013-08-07 00:03:44 0 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql5610//bin/mysqld: ambiguous option '--log=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.log' (log-bin, log_slave_updates)
2013-08-07 00:03:44 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-08-07 00:03:44 0 [Note] Binlog end

================
```

"log=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.log" is defined in the /etc/my.cnf and cant be removed. (Cant be changed as globally used)

I also tried to install using `--defaults-file=/usr/local/mysql5610/my.cnf` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log

> The --log option was removed in MySQL 5.6.1 (along with the log system variable). Instead, use the --general_log option to enable the general query log and the --general_log_file=file_name option to set the general query log file name.

In fact, the `log` option has been deprecated since MySQL 5.1.29 (circa October 2008).

You don't have to remove your my.cnf, but you cannot use the `log` option anymore.  You must change it according to the instructions above, and it will work on all your other instances of MySQL 5.1 and greater.